# Dynamically select TOP rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to select `TOP` rows dynamically?

This code is not working:

```
Declare @Number int
Set @Number= 6

select Top @Number ID from tblEmployee
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in round brackets:

```
select Top (@Number) ID from tblEmployee
```